# How to find the customer's visit is from the Google Results Page

Tags: magento, cookies, google-analytics, utm

As we are moving from the classic google analytics to the Universal google analytics for the marketing requirement, i need to find out from where the customer is coming from. If he is coming from the marketing campaigns then we have the param **utm_source** from url. So with this I can find out the customer visit. But if the customer is from the google results, then there will be no extra parameters added to the URL.

Because of this, I am unable to differentiate whether the customer is from the Google Results or from the **direct URL** visit. My idea is to use, **HTTP_REFERRER**. But this will result in lot of requests to server for each page load which results in unnecessary load on server.

Universal google analytics does support **_utmz** cookies. It will only supported in classic google analytics. So is there any better way to differentiate the customer visit from the **google results** and the **direct URL** visit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about using Google Analytics and is not programing related might be better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Too see if I understand you correctly, you are not talking about the Analytics interface - you want to identify in realtime in your pagecode where users came from, and the old method does not work anymore because Universal Analytics does not store traffic source information on the client side like classic Analytics used to do. Is that it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea to use the referrer is as solid as it gets. You do not need any server roundtrips, since you can access the referrer via Javascript using `document.referrer` - if that is empty you have a direct type-in/bookmark, else you can check against a list of hostnames of search engines. This might not match to 100% with Google Analytics attribution, but should give you a usable approximation (it will obviously only work on the landing page, after that the referrer is your own site).